# Time is converted wrongly on server

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

Time is not converted propely on server , 
I'm converting timestamp , on local host it works well, but on server it's earlier two hours ,

```
$ToConvert = 1570080669;
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp($ToConvert); 
$EndTime = $dt->format('m/d/Y H:i');
echo $EndTime;
```

on local host :

10/03/2019 07:31

on Server :

10/03/2019 05:31

what might be the problem?

Comment: Check the server's time zone.

Comment: Have you tried setting the timezone? date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateTime class in PHP has a method called "setTimezone" which expects an instance of DatetimeZone as an argument. Using your code as an example, you just need to add one extra line as follows:

```
$ToConvert = 1570080669;
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp($ToConvert); 
$dt->setTimezone(new DatetimeZone('Europe/London'));
$EndTime = $dt->format('m/d/Y H:i');
echo $EndTime;
```

You can change the argument when instantiating a new timezone as desired to suit your needs.

More information is on the php.net website:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php